# What's the API for querying Focus mode on iOS 15?

Tags: ios, ios15

iOS 15 introduced Focus mode. Apple mentioned that communication apps can query if the device is currently in Focus so we can tell the other person that they might not be notified of messages. However I couldn't find the API in apple docs. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682143

FocusStatusCenter

```
import Intents

/// Retrieve the current authorization status: INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus
INFocusStatusCenter.default.authorizationStatus

/// Request authorization to check Focus Status
//
INFocusStatusCenter.default.requestAuthorization { status in
    /// Provides a INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus
}

/// Check if Focus is enabled. INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus must be .authorized
INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused
```

You need add `NSFocusStatusUsageDescription` to Info.plist

https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-notification-changes-updates-from-apples-wwdc-21/

Comment: This seems like the best answer given the fairly limited API options. Worth highlighting that you also need to add the "Communication Notifications" capability to your target in order to read the focus status (in addition to requesting authorization in the app itself).

Comment: `INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused` its always return false. even when focus mode is enabled

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/infocusstatus.

Apple states on their iOS 15 Developer Site the following, "With Focus, users can have notifications delivered at times that work best for them and with the Interruption Levels API, you can provide more nuanced delivery with one of four interruption levels (including new Passive and Time-Sensitive levels)." (source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/ios/))

If the above link doesn't help, perhaps the quote above will help.

Answer (score 0):

var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused! it only returns false if the focus Status is off in Settings, Kindly turn on Focus Status, then it will return true.

To do this, GO to the Do not Disturb screen
At the bottom, there will a button "Focus Status" to turn it on
Now try var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused!

Comment: Please format your answer so that the code is clearly differentiated from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused its always return false

And

> var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused! it only returns false if the focus Status is off in Settings, Kindly turn on Focus Status, then it will return true.

> To do this, GO to the Do not Disturb screen At the bottom, there will a button "Focus Status" to turn it on Now try var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused!

It is wrong!

If you haven't tried it, please don't copy and paste to mislead people who need answers! This is very irresponsible!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35741673)