# iOS API for enable / disable focus mode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, notifications, focus

Apple introduced focus modes in iOS 15:
https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/06/ios-15-brings-powerful-new-features-to-stay-connected-focus-explore-and-more/

Is it possible to enable or disable one of these focus modes programmatically in an app?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to set focus modes; This is something that the user controls, not apps.

Comment: Can we on code check if we are on focus mode or not ?

Comment: @tamtoum1987 As of iOS 15 you can check for `isFocused`, but not which Focus mode, and you can only check if you’re a communication app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716473/whats-the-api-for-querying-focus-mode-on-ios-15