# ReactNative check if we are on focus mode on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, focus

On iOS 15 we have possibility to be on focus mode
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608
I know it's impossible de set focus mode programmatically what i need is just check if we are on focus mode or not programmatically

How can i check if we are on focus mode on an application reactnative, the client want to block user to access to a specific screen if the user hasn't enable focus mode on parameters

How can i do that on reactnative for ios device

any help would be greatly appreciated

---

Edit

i use this part of code :

```
/// Retrieve the current authorization status: INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus
let authorizationStatus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.authorizationStatus

/// Request authorization to check Focus Status
//
INFocusStatusCenter.default.requestAuthorization { status in
    /// Provides a INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus
}

/// Check if Focus is enabled. INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus must be .authorized
let focused = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused

return ["focused": focused!, "authorizationStatus": authorizationStatus];
```

but the focused variable is always false, even if i active the focus mode on parameters and i don't receive any notification when the application is active, why INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused is never true ? INFocusStatusAuthorizationStatus is authorized

Comment: Already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716473/whats-the-api-for-querying-focus-mode-on-ios-15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the API for querying Focus mode on iOS 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716473/whats-the-api-for-querying-focus-mode-on-ios-15)

Comment: Can't find a response for objective c, this answer is for swift