# Check focus mode status with swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, focus

How to check if focus mode is enabled?

I am using the following code.

```
var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused!
```

but it always returns false. doesn't matter whether focus mode is enabled or not.

taking the guide from this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278761/8894035
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/infocusstatuscenter

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? It just started all of sudden.

Comment: @Ryan ... nop. I never played with focus mode after this.

Answer (score 0):

var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused!
it only returns false if the focus Status is off in Settings, Kindly turn on Focus Status, then it will return **true**.

1. To do this, GO to the Do not Disturb screen
2. At the bottom, there will a button "Focus Status" to turn it on
3. Now try var isFocus = INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus.isFocused!

Comment: Please format your answer in order to better differentiate code snippets from comments.